# Bootstrap table styles not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-tables

I'm sure this is just something stupid, but I've copied the table header formatting example from bootstraps website [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/#table-head-options) but it isn't actually changing the table header color.  What am I doing wrong?

Running the code snippet shows the behavior I am describing when I want it to look like:
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
      <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Username</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Different version of Bootstrap? You link BS3 but the stying comes from BS4. That class `thead-inverse` does not exist in BS3 I think.

Comment: The example website is Bootstrap [v4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/), the code you posted is using a stylesheet from Bootstrap [v3](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables).

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"` use this

Comment: Dang it, that's definitely it.